# How do I prevent superfluous newlines from appearing in my regex matches?

Tags: python, regex

I have the folowing string

```
'TOKEN a$dmin\r\n'
```

And I would like to extract the value `'a$dmin'` from it. I'm using

```
re.findall("(?i)TOKEN (.*)",string)
```

but what I'm getting is `'a$dmin\r\n'`

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: You're not getting `'a$dmin\r\n'`. You're getting `'a$dmin\r'`, right?

Comment: Nope, I'm getting \r\n at the end.

Comment: I find that hard to believe (and can't reproduce it here) because the regex dot does explicitly not match newlines. Which Python version is this? Can you copy/paste a relevant section of the Python shell that shows this behaviour?

Comment: Just for a giggle, does the string end with a carriage-return and a linefeed, or with the literal four-character sequence `\r\n`?

Comment: It's carriage-return and a linefeed, please don't giggle at n00bs :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either match against `str.strip`:

```
re.findall(r"(?i)TOKEN (\S*)", s.strip())
```

or change the expression to match only non-spaces:

```
re.findall(r"(?i)TOKEN (\S*)", s)
```

In case you have literal slashes, as in:

```
s = r'TOKEN a$dmin\r\n'
```

use this expression to match everything before the first slash:

```
re.findall(r"(?i)TOKEN (.*?)\\", s)
```

Comment: +1 Didn't realize this included my solution as well as other good solutions.

Comment: Or you could just run the regex on string.strip() ... (unless they're literal backslashes which I doubt is the case).

Comment: I suppose `split` is meant to be `strip` in the first solution?